# What is the equivalent of Cypress.env() in playwright

Tags: javascript, yaml, playwright

May I know what is the equivalent of the `cypress.env()` in playwright.

We have below line of code in yml file in Cypress

```
CYPRESS_test_suite: 'Smoke tests'
```

Then in 1 of our spec file we have this line of code

```
const test_suite = Cypress.env('test_suite')
```

I would like to do it also in playwright but I am not able to find any references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parameterize#passing-environment-variables), you can use process `.env` variables:

```
const test_suite = process.env.VARIABE_NAME // e.g. 'test_suite'
```

or

```
const test_suite = process.env.CYPRESS_VARIABLE_NAME
```

if you want to use the variable from cypress env

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to tag your tests, for example as a 'smoke_test', Playwright has other ways to support this beyond `process.env.{variable}` with the `tag` attribute.

```
test('user can login', { tag: ['@smoke', '@e2e' ] }, async ({ page }) => {
  // write test });
});
```

which can then be ran with

`npx playwright test --grep @smoke`

and will be appropriately tagged for filtering in subsequent test reports.

This is available in Playwright versions >= 1.4.2.